# react native table cells custom background colors

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I would like to present my json data in table like format with
custom background colors for cells.

JSON file has an extra 0-10 number for each cell value. larger number should be darker.

Could have the color hex codes added to my JSON file on the remote server for less work on the react native side.

Please see attached image for example.

[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up with this, works fine for the time being...

```
import { Col, Row, Grid } from "react-native-easy-grid";

<View>
    <Grid>
        <Row>
            <Col size={50}>
                <Text style={{backgroundColor: item.ip_count_bgcolor}}>
                    {item.ip_address}
                </Text>
            </Col>
            <Col size={50}>
                <Text style={{backgroundColor: item.software_count_bgcolor}}>
                    {item.software}
                </Text>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Grid>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 : If you don't have color saved along with JSON**

Try this code snipped, assuming you are using some kind map function to display cells. I am not sure how scalable or heavy this is as it calls a function for each cell to determine its colors.

```
checkColors(value) {
    if(value > 5) {
        return { backgroundColor:'red' }
    } else if (value > 4) {
        return { backgroundColor:'green' }
    } else if (value > 3) {
        return { backgroundColor:'white' }
    }
}

return yourvalues.map((eachItem) => {
    return (
        <View style={ this.checkColors(eachItem.value) }>
            <Text>Sample</Text>
        </View>
    )
})
```

**Solution 2: If you have color code along with values of each cell**

```
return yourvalues.map((eachItem) => {
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: eachItem.colorValue }}>
            <Text>Sample</Text>
        </View>
    )
})
```